# Unit testing with complex object dependency

Tags: java, unit-testing

I need to unit test several methods similar to following method. Class ProductItem is petty complex and it is nested. One way to test this method is that I take my time and build an object for ProductItem and pass it to the method, but I feel that it is too tedious. Is there any good way to test it without building the entire object?

```
public BigDecimal getSubtotal(ProductItem ip) {
    return ip.getTotal().subtract(ip.getTotalTax())
            .subtract(ip.getShipping());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mocking library such as Mockito. For instance:

```
final ProductItem mock = mock(ProductItem.class);
when(mock.getTotal()).thenReturn(something);
// same for .getTotalTax(), .getShipping()
```

Then you can test your `.getSubtotal()` method:

```
// Using BigDecimal's .compareTo() for reliable results...
// "0" and "0.0" are not .equals() with BigDecimal!
assertTrue(xxx.getSubtotal(mock).compareTo(expectedResult) == 0);
```

Note that methods which you do not stub this way will return default values: 0 for primitives, null for objects and false for booleans.

Note 2: requires that `ProductItem` is not `final` and that methods you stub are not `final` either; otherwise you'll have to use PowerMockito and have to write quite some glue as well...

Note 3: works for abstract classes and interfaces as well; you can `mock(Comparator.class)` for instance

Comment: Why do we use final for mock here?

Comment: Not sure what you call state testing here?

Comment: @user3123690 as to `final`, well, it's my coding style, nothing else ;)

Comment: if you look at http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html sectin 2.3, it mentions state testing.